# How to scrape img src value of each li tag

Tags: php, regex

```
<ul class="vehicle__gallery cf">
<li><a href="#"><img src="AETV19098412_2a.jpg"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="AETV19098412_3a.jpg"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="AETV19098412_4a.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
```

and my preg match syntax is as below:

```
preg_match_all('/<ul class="vehicle__gallery cf">.*?<li>.*?<a(.*?)href="(.*?)"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>.*?<\/li>.*?<\/ul>/s', $html_image,$posts, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Comment: Are you able to use JavaScript or better JQuery? Then it is way mor easy and clean to extract the data you need and pass it via Ajax becaues this can work but if you make only add one parameter later or maybe do an accidental space between html attributes this code will not work anymore. Its a very hacky solution. Otherwise, are you not able to use a form instead to pass your image data to your script?

Answer (score 1):

Please [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454) use regular expressions to parse HTML. PHP has a fine [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) implementation you can use to [`loadHTML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) and [`query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) it with [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/) expressions such as `//ul/li/a/img/@src` to retrieve what you're after, or maybe [import](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-import-dom.php) it as a [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) object if you prefer that toolset.

#### Example:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<ul class="vehicle__gallery cf">
<li><a href="#"><img src="AETV19098412_2a.jpg"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="AETV19098412_3a.jpg"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="AETV19098412_4a.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$imgs = $xpath->query("//ul/li/a/img/@src");

foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    echo $img->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```

#### Output:

```
AETV19098412_2a.jpg
AETV19098412_3a.jpg
AETV19098412_4a.jpg
```

Comment: could you elaborate your answer for how?

Comment: @AvinashRaj that would be another question as i said.let OP try to use the library.

Comment: @Anirudha i don't think that would be an another question. He's asking how i parse  this html file and to get the value of a particular tag. Your answer is simply asking him to use dom parser. You need to guide him how to do that using a dom parser. A link(good if it's a SO link) mentioning this(how to parseout text inside a particular tag using dom parser) would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You dont use regex to parse HTML.It wont work.

- `<li>` tags dont always have ending tag nor do `<img>` tag.
- There can be n number of attributes to a tag
- attribute values don't always go in double quotes

Use an html parser like [simpledomparser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

I wont even attempt to come up with a regex for this because at some point it would fail.

Comment: @Anirudha your answer `Use an html parser like simpledomparser` would be a comment not as an answer. Provide the solution for how to get the values inside `<img src` tag using dom parser.

Comment: @AvinashRaj OP is asking for a regex solution and the ans to it is "no". As far as the solution is concerned let him post a new question if he's facing any problem using the library. That would be another question and to be honest i dont know PHP

Answer (score -1):

If you give your img tags a class or something, for example:

```
<img class="gallery_item" src="AETV19098412_2a.jpg">
<img class="gallery_item" src="AETV19098412_3a.jpg">
```

you can do more easy:

```
preg_match('/<img class="gallery_item" src="(.*)">/');
```

However this is still very hacky, if you ever add a css class, html attributes or modify your code you have the problem that your code might not work anymore.

This solution is anything else then clean and you should considerung using JQuery or a form as stated in my comment before would make your life alot easier and the code will not break because of future, minor html changes that might come up any day.

Comment: hi, `.*` should be `.*?`..although there are a lot of cases where the regex would fail,am afraid..

Comment: Well I stated that this is very risky, I just provided a PHP-based solution because the author asked for it. And (.*) is correct and will work aslong as there are no extra spaces or any other attributes interfering here.

Answer (score -1):

Another approach is use javascript (jquery).

```
var imgArr = []
$("ul.vehicle__gallery li img").each(function(){
     imgArr.push($(this).attr('src'));
})
```

Comment: This would work fine but we need to check back with OP if he's fine using jquery. He's using php (P.S i didnt downvote)

Comment: Yes, I just give my solutions based on my usual thinking..
Anyway, if he is votedown, I will remove my answer.